# How to perform log-rank test correctly on IPTW weighted groups?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, survival, sample-weighting

Thank you very much for your attetion!

I am working on an observation study with time-to-event data. The data has multiple covariates say V1-V5. I want to evaluate the treatment effect, so I used IPTW (weightit package) to balance V1-V5. Balance was achieved between treatment group after IPTW. However, the **KM curve and log-rank P doesn't quite match**, which confused me a lot.

Below is how I perform the analysis:

1. I first evaluate the treatment effect without balancing. I draw the KM curve and calculated the log-rank p value, I found the curve overlap each other and P is not significant

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
fit_surv <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ treat, data = data)
ggsurvplot(fit_surv, data = data, pval = T, pval.method = T)
```

[image]
2. Then I performed IPTW weighting using WeightIt package, again, I draw the KM curve and calculated the log-rank p value. However, I found **the curve well-separated to each other but P remain unchanged**!

```
library(WeightIt)
W.out <- weightit(treat ~  V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5,
                  data = data, estimand = "ATT", method = "ebal")
data$weight <- W.out$weights
fit_surv <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ treat, data = data, weights = data$weight)
ggsurvplot(fit_surv, data = data, pval = T, pval.method = T)
```

[image]

Why a separated KM curve yield exact the same P value? I'm afraid of using the wrong test method.
When analysing weighted samples in a time-to-event data, what is the correct way of testing the survival difference?
Should I use `survival::coxph(weight = ...)` instead?
Any suggestions and comments are highly welcome!

Comment: You did not provide any motivation for the need for IPTW vs. the more direct, interpretable, and powerful (by a lot) direct covariate adjustment.  Weighting methods lose a lot of efficiency.

Comment: Dear community: I found the answer to my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690690/survdiff-package-survival-with-frequency-weights-obtained-after-coarsened-exa

Answer (score 0):

@Frank Harrell
I'm not a statistics major, but I'll try to present a few motivations for using IPTW from a non-expert perspective. Assuming that by "covariate adjustment" you mean multiple covariate Cox regression:

1. IPTW allows for adjustment of more parameters. I once attended a lecture on your modeling strategy, and multiple regression had a rule of thumb of "10 events to 1 variable." Additionally, in your comment on another question on this website, you mentioned that IPTW only requires "4 events to 1 variable." In my small-sample study, this can help me balance more covariates, whereas in multiple regression, I need to consider how many degrees of freedom I can afford.
2. The entropy balancing algorithm in IPTW can achieve perfect matching of covariates between two groups. At the same time, I will report the effective sample size after weighting in the study results.
3. I'm unsure if the effects of covariates are linear. Assuming non-linear effects would increase the cost of degrees of freedom in Cox multiple regression.
4. In IPTW, I only need to perform simple tests on the balanced groups. Balanced survival curves are more intuitive, and I can easily obtain effect sizes through Cox univariate regression.

Comment: That's problematic in a number of ways. (1) 10 events:variable is a very crude sample size calculation. (2) It applies to predictive accuracy of predictive models whereas you are in an adjustment context where overfitting is not nearly as problematic; (3) IPTW without direct handling of weight uncertainties has been shown to be very problematic, and you'll find that weight uncertainties are huge with small sample sizes; (4) failure to condition on important prognostic factors that directly predict event times results in more violations of the proportional hazards assumption; (5) interpretation

Comment: Thank you for clarifying several misuderstandings. I will consider multivariate cox regression analysis as a sensitive analysis.

Comment: Note that _multivariate_ refers to multiple _dependent_ variables.  The correct terminology in your case is _multivariable_.

Comment: Thank you so much professor